# Setting the HTML5 form fields opened in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, html, ios4, uiwebview

I am building an application that loads a HTML5 form in `UIWebView`, I have to set the form fields using the program when the page is first loaded.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` as the following:

```
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var UsernameField = document.getElementById('UsernameField');"  
                     "UsernameField.value='Username';"];
```

You might be interested in calling `JavaScript` onLoad function and pass the text fields values.

Please go to this link for more details:

[How To Inject JavaScript Functions Into a UIWebView](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview)

---

Please Try this Code snippet:

Create a JavaScript Method called `setColor`

```
 function setColor()
 {
     document.getElementById('UserNameField').value = "setColor Function Called"; 
 }
```

Now in the objective c:

```
 NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"setColor();"];

 [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
```

Comment: Thanx Ahmad, but this solution is not working. For the wholw day I tried the thing but it seems that UIWebView is not setting the field values. However, if I execute any other java script statement, they work fine.
Can you please comment on this issue. Also, does UIWebView have problems in executing JavaScipts?

Comment: Ahmad it seems that the UIWebView is not supporting the DOM features. I am using the same code snippet. The value of element is set by the function (checked using alert box), but it is not displayed in the web page. Do, I have to add something that makes this possible?

Comment: Got the problem.... 
I was using autofocus attribute of the input tag. This tag did seems to create problem. I removed it and all my java scripts works fine. May be webkit doesn't have support for autofocus. Need to google it....

Comment: I am very glad you reached this